# Why doesn't the body become the width I specify?

Tags: html, css, html-table

Why is this sample table, the body does not have the specified width?

```
<html>  
<head>  
   <style type="text/css">  
     table{   
border-collapse:collapse;  
     }  
     table,th, td{    
        border: 4px, solid;  
     }  

     #article{
background-color: #FDF8AB;  
border: 3px solid #85A110;  
width: 760px;  
margin-top: 20px; 
margin-left: auto;  
     margin-right: auto;  
   }  
   </style>  
</head>  
<body  id="article">  
<div>
<table>  
<tr>  
    <th>First Name</th>   
    <th>Last Name</th>   
    <th>Date</th>   
    <th>Notes</th>   
</tr>   
<tr>   
    <td>Jill</td>   
    <td>Smith</td>  
    <td>20-12-2013</td>  
    <td>AAAa</td>  
</tr>  

<tr>  
    <td>Jill</td>  
    <td>Smith</td>   
    <td>20-12-2013</td>  
    <td>AAAa</td>  
</tr>  

<tr>  
    <td>Eve </td>  
    <td>Jackson</td>  
    <td>20-12-2013</td>  
    <td>AAAa</td>   
</tr>  

<tr>  
    <td>John </td>  
    <td>Doe</td>  
    <td>20-12-2013</td>  
    <td>AAAa</td>  
</tr>  

<tr>  
    <td>Adam </td>  
    <td>Johnson</td>  
    <td>20-12-2013</td>  
    <td>AAAa</td>  
</tr>  


</table>  

 </div>

</body>  
</html>
```

Comment: Looks fine here - http://jsfiddle.net/wWY7m/

Comment: @Zenith:What do you mean fine? The body covers all the browser but I have put `auto` and `width` of `760px`. I expected it would be centered in the middle of the browser window

Comment: Not sure if it's a typo but in your code you close the div before closing the table.

Comment: @j08691:Thanks!It was a typo.

Comment: @Jim What you are exactly looking for?

Comment: @Mr.Alien:I was expecting that the body's border would appear as a square centered in the browser window (`auto`) with a width of `760px`. Right now it just expands to cover all browser window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using

```
#article {
   background-color: #FDF8AB; /* Other Styles */
}
```

So when you are not using any background color for your `html` element, the next parent level element is `body` and so you are confused, provide a background color to `html` element and you'll see the difference

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/QLeFy/)

My Suggestion:

You should not use `fixed` width for `body` tag, let it be `width: 100%;` which it is, by default, as it's a *block level element*, instead, wrap your `table` inside a container `div`, use *fixed width* and *auto margins* for this `div` which will give you the desired effect and also in a neat way

[**The Right Way**](http://jsfiddle.net/Nz4g7/)

Comment: I added `html {
    background: #fff;
}` but nothing changed (although what you say makes sense).

Comment: @Jim Don't resize the body, instead nest a child element and use a fixed width with auto margins, see the demo :)

Comment: :Ok I will see the demo, but how come is your first fiddle different than mine? I see that the surrounding color of your html is white.That does not happen for me.

Comment: @Jim See the css wndow, I've added `html {background: #fff;}`

Comment: @Jim Do the right way, read my suggestion, what you are doing is wrong :)

Answer (score 2):

You should place everything within the body into a div or section container/wrapper. 
You define a width on the wrapper. 
You apply a style to the body of text-align center.
So that the div#container or section#content has a defined width and margin:0 auto;.

Also if you have a 3px border, your width with be  width + border left + border right.  So that's where the extra 6 pixels are coming from.

Comment: Added `body{ text-align:center; }` but no effect

Comment: your container/wrapper has to have a defined width and a margin:0 auto for it to center on the page.

It's not the body that you need to set the width on, it's the container.